# What is "shadow" configuration space?

Tags: pcie, pci

In a github project I saw a feature as follows:

> Support for writing to custom shadow configuration space.

I know what PCI config space is but what is a "shadow configuration space"? I google'd but could not come across anything that explains it clearly.

Here is the link to the project: https://github.com/ufrisk/LeechCore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a shadow memory space/configuration/… is a memory that is a copy of the original.

It can be used to fallback in case of a problem arises, for example when you write the original configuration and there is a power down during writing. The system can detect the configuration space is not written correctly, and can copy the shadow memory to the original.